# elixir map.put not updating map

Tags: elixir

I have a function that has a Map `%{}` as its param

```
def set_data (data) do
...
end
```

I am trying to update the param `data` using `map.put`.

`data` is a flat map like so

```
%{
 a: ...
 b: ...
 c: ...
}
```

What I have an issue with is setting a key/property in the `data` map with another map that looks like this:

```
ModuleA.EctoSchemaMap{
 some_key: nil,
 another_key: ModuleB.EctoSchemaMap{
  inner_key_a: "456",
  inner_key_b: nil
 }
}
```

This map above `ModuleA.EctoSchemaMap` is returned from a function call like so

`some_data = get_data()`

So `some_data` = `ModuleA.EctoSchemaMap` map above.

For some reason, when I try to update the key `b` in the param `data` map in the function, everything will copy over that is a `nil` value in the `ModuleA.EctoSchemaMap` map, but the key `inner_key_a` shows as nil as well, even though before `some_data` shows `inner_key_a` is not `nil`

```
data
|> map.put(:a, "123")
|> map.put(:b, some_data)
```

After doing the piping above, I was expecting `data` to have `:b` updated with the value

```
b: ModuleA.EctoSchemaMap{
    some_key: nil,
    another_key: ModuleB.EctoSchemaMap{
     inner_key_a: "456", //I need this value to be there
     inner_key_b: nil
    }
   }
```

but it is instead showing this

```
b: ModuleA.EctoSchemaMap{
    some_key: nil,
    another_key: ModuleB.EctoSchemaMap{
     inner_key_a: nil, //NOT sure why this is being set as nil even though `some_data` had a value for this
     inner_key_b: nil
    }
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure,  its `map` instead of `Map`?

Comment: How are getting to know that it is updating the original map for key `:a_key`? Please add the checking code which is updatinb the original map.

Comment: Its a `Map` like so `%{}`

Comment: I know `:a_key` is updating because I am printing `data_map` to console and it shows the new data is there. It also shows on the front end.

Comment: Ah, if it is so, then I am confused. Afaik, the Elixir is a immutable language. It doesn't mutates any of the data. May be I am missing something. More experienced peopes will answer it. I have followed, bookmarked and upvoted the question.

Comment: Could you please once try the assignment as I suggested  in my answer and check if it is working?

Comment: Can you please show a complete code example?  It will help you get better responses if you can show us _exactly_ what you're running and what you're expecting it to return.

Comment: Okay, I updated the question.

Comment: @hnhl - please include a working code snippet. You have included multiple pieces that don't add to a full, executable script. It's difficult to judge what the problem might be - it might be something with Ecto, or related to immutability. If you can't post your actual code for some reason, try to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Your latest edit is an improvement, thanks, but you still have not included a working code snippet, i.e. something with actual values that we can cut/paste into `iex` and help debug.

Answer (score 4):

All the data structures are immuatable in Elixir. In the code, `Map.put` creates a new copy of the map with your given key-value added/updated. But it is not storing anywhere. So, reassigne the variable `data_map`

```
data_map = data_map
|> map.put(:some_key, data)
```

Since your have only one operation in the pipe, the recommended way to it is-

```
data_map = Map.put(data_map, :some_key, data)
```

Also note that it is `Map` not `map`.

Comment: Sorry I couldnt follow, are you suggesting to not use the pipe and to just do this `data_map = Map.put(data_map, :some_key, data)`? Also, There are other map.puts and it is updating the original Map. Its just for this particular key that doesn't get updated. I updated my post to show

Comment: @hnhl I am suggesting not use pipe if you are doing only 
 one opertaion in the pipe.

Comment: it is more than one operation

Comment: @hnhl Yeh, it wasn't in the first revision of the question. That's why I recommend it. Never mind.

Comment: I rewrote question to be more clear on my problem